# SQL - Select records with duplication in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Is there a way to select records with duplication within 1 column?

So, for instance you have Address_Table:

| Address_Line_1 | Address_Line_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 street | Town |
| 321 street 321 street 321 street | Town |
| 456 street | Town |
| 789 street 789 street | Town |

Is there a way to select the all records like 321 & 789 street from the Address_Line_1 column that contain duplicates of themselves?

Thanks

Comment: Would 789 street and 789 st be considered a duplicate ?

Comment: Does a space always separate duplicates, ie, "456 street,456 street 456 street" could never occur?

Comment: How about 789 street and 789 street Apt B ?   Parsing addresses can be a slippery slope.  You'd be amazed at the variations of "boulevard"  alone.

Comment: They're always separated by spaces, I'm not too concerned with being 100% accurate just need to find as many dupes as possible for re-processing. Even if I pick up a few legitimate records re-processing them wouldn't do anything to them. Trying to cut down processing time by not re-processing them all.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, and not fully tested.

```
Select A.* 
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                select Dupes = Avg(Hits)   -- perhaps Max(Hits) instead
                 From (
                        Select Value
                              ,Hits   = sum(1) over (partition by Value)
                         From  string_split([Address_Line_1],' ')
                       ) B1
             ) B
 Where Dupes>1
```

**Results**

```
Address_Line_1                      Address_Line_2
321 street 321 street 321 street    Town
789 street 789 street               Town
```

Answer (score 0):

If your databse COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL  more than 130

```
ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
```

You can try this

```
SELECT ads = STUFF((
     SELECT ' ' + value
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(Address_Line_1, ' ')
        GROUP BY value
        FOR XML PATH('')
     ), 1, 1, '') , Address_Line_1, Address_Line_2 FROM Adress
```

[Fidler Sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a5f7da71ca24cd11fc472c22c6a303e9)

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2GKJ.png)